# Unable to update entity from Spring boot scheduled task

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, scheduled-tasks

I am running a spring boot scheduled task

```
@Scheduled(cron="mycronexpression")
public void myTask(){
  Myentity e=myRepo.getById(1);
  System.out.println("BeforeValue"+e.getProp());
  e.setProp(null);
  myRepo.save(e);
  System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Here, both the prinntln statements print the values properly. But,I get an error saying "UnExpected error occurred in scheduled task. Could not commit JPA transaction.Error while committing the transaction."

The same code works fine if I call it from a controller(via postman). So this is nothing to do with DB constraints. Also,if I don't do e.setProp(null), it doesn't fail.
By the way, the component where I am calling this is marked as @Transactional.

Any suggestions will help me a lot.

Comment: was your repo properly injected btw?

Comment: just asking is the prop is nullable in table ?

Comment: @im_infamous. Yes, the get is working fine.

Comment: @Shawrup yes.prop is nullable  in table. As I have mentioned, when I put the same code into a service and call it from a controller via postman, it works fine.

Comment: I am getting the mentioned error only for jpa save as mentioned in the question

Comment: full stack trace please.